# Counting rows from a text file

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create a Python code that will count the number of rows in a text file. However, it will not recognize the for statement as it gives me errors on the indentation below it.

```
#*********************end of sec 1*****************************
item=open("back.txt","r")
i=0
countlist=[line.strip() for line in item]#seperate lines
        i=1+i
print i
item.close()
```

Comment: Is the i=1+i line supposed to be indented like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
print len(list(open("some_file.txt")))
```

no need for `with ...` or closing files... this wont keep a reference to the fh so it should garbage collect and destroy just fine

Comment: Only works on CPython, and it reads the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: You could `for line in lines` after opening the file, but then you're writing up a loop by hand, even though you're not loading the whole file into memory at once...trade-offs for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
with open("back.txt", "r") as backfile:
    lines = backfile.readlines()
    return len(lines)
```

Comment: Why loading all the lines into memory?

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("back.txt") as f:
    print len(f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for line in item:
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('back.txt', 'r') as item:
    nbr = sum(1 for i in item)
```

Generator expression that should not keep to much unneeded in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The for is encapsulated in the brackets and the i=1+i is not within the scope of the for loop. Therefore, the i=1+1 should not be indented.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a `for` loop. You have a list comprehension. A list comprehension doesn't allow or require an indented block of statements to execute on each iteration; it just builds a list. If you only want the number of rows, you want this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    rowcount = sum(1 for line in f)
```

This closes the file when you're done, even on Python implementations other than CPython, and it doesn't store the whole file in memory, so it works on huge files. If you need an actual list of the rows, you want this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    rows = [line.strip() for line in f]
rowcount = len(rows)
```